# Unable to install any packages using yum repo

Tags: docker, subscription, yum, repo, rhel8

Please help to fix the below error.

```
# yum install docker
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for s390x - AppStream from RHUI (RPMs)                                      2.4 kB/s | 169  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms':
  - Status code: 403 for https://rhui.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/content/content/dist/rhel8/rhui/8/s390x/appstream/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 44.197.135.178)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
[root@k8s-master yum.repos.d]#
```

Even after disabling "`rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms`" repo from subscription manager, this error persists.

```
[root@k8s-master yum.repos.d]# subscription-manager repos --disable rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
Repositories disabled by configuration.

[root@k8s-master yum.repos.d]# subscription-manager refresh
All local data refreshed
[root@k8s-master yum.repos.d]# yum clean all
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
13 files removed
[root@k8s-master yum.repos.d]#
```

Comment: It says it tried all the mirrors. Are you sure you have a working internet connection?

Comment: Yes. I am using this instance from AWS. So, it has internet connection.